# how to calculate column based on a first value (pandas)(python)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I has such a data frame using python pandas:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZgWV.png)

how can i calculate rest of the column dividing every new cell by 2?

so the result must be:

- 0.05646
- 0.02823
- 0.014115

also this doesn't work:
`table['HAopen'][1:24] = (table['HAopen'].shift() )/2`

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a list of 2^{index} and divide it by `HAopen` column

```py
out = df['HAopen'].ffill().div(list(map(lambda x: pow(2,x), df.index)))
```

```
print(out)

0    0.056460
1    0.028230
2    0.014115
3    0.007058
4    0.003529
Name: HAopen, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` for efficiency:

```
import numpy as np
df['HAopen'].ffill().div(2**np.arange(len(df)))
```

output:

```
0    0.056460
1    0.028230
2    0.014115
3    0.007058
4    0.003529
5    0.001764
Name: HAopen, dtype: float64
```